# WCF with Win Auth doesn't work in IIS Express

Tags: wcf

**NOTE:** I did a test, just creating a new project and setting Anonymous to False and WinAuth to True (via Visual Studio) and happens the same

It works on IIS, but not in IIS Express.

I am using Windows Authentication. I configured WinAuth enabled and Anonymous disabled on both IIS/Express.

See the applicationhost.config:

```
<location path="/Services">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
                <basicAuthentication enabled="false" /> <!--Its a try -->
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

At WCF web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" /><!--Its a try -->
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <!--Log de Erros -->
        <add name="ErrorLogging" type="ErrorHandlerBehavior, MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding>
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <ErrorLogging />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When I use IIS Express it returns the error:

The authentication schemes configured on the host ('IntegratedWindowsAuthentication') do not allow those configured on the binding 'BasicHttpBinding' ('Anonymous').  Please ensure that the SecurityMode is set to Transport or TransportCredentialOnly.  Additionally, this may be resolved by changing the authentication schemes for this application through the IIS management tool, through the ServiceHost.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemes property, in the application configuration file at the  element, by updating the ClientCredentialType property on the binding, or by adjusting the AuthenticationScheme property on the HttpTransportBindingElement.

Comment: Could you share the rest of the service config file with the endpoint configuration? You may need to specify the bindingConfiguration by name.

Comment: Since the error indicates the binding configuration is not correct, give the bindingConfiguration a name: <binding name="basicConfig">. Then configure two endpoints for your service, one for the basicHttpBinding and on for mexHttpBinding. Point the basicHttpBinding to the basicConfig using the bindingConfiguration="basicConfig" attribute.